# Need tkinter on my python 3.6 installation (Windows 10)

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter

I'm running Python 3.6 on a Windows 10 machine. I want to display a simple matplotlib plot like this:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.arange(0, 5, 0.1);
y = np.sin(x)
plt.plot(x, y)
```

Unfortunately, I get the error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tkinter'
```

I try installing tkinter through my terminal:

```
> pip install tkinter
Collecting tkinter
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tkinter (from versions: )
  No matching distribution found for tkinter
```

I also tried `pip install python3-tk` but without success. I found a couple of posts on StackOverflow explaining how to install tkinter properly, but they're all about Python 2 and/or Linux systems. I couldn't find a post particularly for Python 3.6 on Windows 10.

Comment: Does `import tkinter` work?  If it does tkinter is installed.  Tkinter is installed by default on all Windows machines as far as I know so it seems to be a mathplotlib problem.

Comment: Nope, it doesn't work. I've installed my Python from the official python website.

Comment: maybe use [Anaconda distribution](https://www.continuum.io/downloads) instead of official version.

Comment: Hi @furas. There is  a specific reason why I cannot use Anaconda. Is there another option?

Comment: there is [Unofficial Windows Binaries for Python Extension Packages](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/) but I doubt you find `tkinter` there. `tkinter` should be preinstalled with `Python` automatically. BTW: `tkinter` is a wrapper on language `tcl/tk` which should be preinstalled with `Python` automatically too. But maybe it didn't do it.

Comment: BTW: which file did you use to install it - `web installer`, `executable installer` or `embeddable zip` ? I don't use Windows but maybe this information helps someone else give you some clue.

Comment: BTW: and maybe add which version did you install `3.6.3`, `3.6.4rc1`

Comment: I currently have version `3.6.1`. I will reinstall python to the latest version and let you know what happens :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it working now. I removed my `Python 3.6.1` installation and installed `Python 3.6.3` from here:

https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-363/

I selected the **Windows x86-64 executable installer** for my Windows 10 computer. While installing, I chose for "custom installation" so I can check which modules I want or don't want. Apparently, tkinter is present by default. Perhaps I had unchecked it on my last installation (a couple of months ago)?

Anyway, I got things working now. But it seems still a bit odd to me that I had to do a complete reinstallation for this to work. A simple `pip install tkinter` should also do the job (in my opinion).

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about windows but in Ubuntu you could do

`sudo apt-get install python3-tk`

For windows you can try 

`import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('agg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`

if you dont want to use `tkinter` at all. (Tested in Ubuntu)

Also dont forget to use `%matplotlib inline` at the top of your notebook if using one.

Answer (score 0):

OK that is weird it worked like that, I had to re-install before and actually downgrade for it to work and uninstall on windows and have issues on linux also. I've done pip for both and everything else. Windows got it working from downgrading from 3.7 to 3.6 and uninstalling 3.7. So that may help someone.

Also a key factor is having access or a clear 'path' to C:\User\"UserName"\appdata from there usually \local but can be \roaming and it ccan appear in a file that is just named python with the version number after or \Local\packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.python.3.7 or many other files it has shown up in, due to what seems random half the time I read about these occurances and even on Pythons help page, they suggest all the places without giving reason for why it would be in each, seeming like it is almost random.